# How to add/install UEFI driver

Tags: boot, drivers, bios, uefi, bootloader

I have written my own UEFI Driver using EDK2 from tianocore. I want it to be run each time an OS loads. Do I need to modify the `bootmgfw.efi`? How to pass control to my `BootCheck.efi` and only after it executes load Windows?

One more question, how can I add a flag, which I can use in my driver? I need it to be set to `0` at first launch, and then `1` in subsequent boots.

I would appreciate a step by step guide or any useful information, thank you.

@Edit:
If that's possible, I would prefer it to be installed using pendrive or disk.

Comment: Did you read the UEFI Driver Writers Guide?

Comment: @fpmurhpy Sorry for the late reply, i saw there three options where one of them was described: EFI System Partition ( [link](https://edk2-docs.gitbooks.io/edk-ii-uefi-driver-writer-s-guide/32_distributing_uefi_drivers/323_efi_system_partition.html) )
There are two 'steps':
1. Copy driver onto UEFI storage. 
How do I transfer the driver onto PC? Does this have to be another UEFI Application? Maybe I can create an UEFI image and inject this driver using Windows somehow?
2. Update the Driver#### and DriverOrder
Can this be done by my own driver using UEFI Shell Protocol?

Answer (score 3):

UEFI Driver Writer's Guide states the following [3 methods](https://edk2-docs.gitbooks.io/edk-ii-uefi-driver-writer-s-guide/32_distributing_uefi_drivers/) to install UEFI drivers:

## 1. Integrated into the platform firmware FLASH image.

One would have to work with the platform manufacturer to do so. Platform manufacturers are usually your hardware OEMs (e.g. HP, Gigabyte, etc). During manufacturing, the OEM would package all UEFI drivers they want to install into a firmware image and flash it (i.e. save it into the flash chip on the motherboard). They would eventually close the chipset's manufacturing mode, thus preventing any 3rd party modifications to it. To update the firmware, one would need to create an update capsule and sign it with the OEM's private key. [Some OEMs made the mistake of not closing the manufacturing mode](https://2016.zeronights.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Intel-BootGuard.pdf), so one (including bootkits/rootkits) could leverage this to install their own UEFI drivers into the firmware. However that is a very complex task and most OEMs have corrected this issue, so it is not worthwhile to go down this path.

However doing so is much easier on a VMware image, so you can follow this [guide](https://github.com/pbatard/efifs/wiki/Adding-a-driver-to-a-UEFI-firmware) if you're interested to try things out.

## 2. PCI Option ROM on a PCI add-in card.

I suppose you're not developing a PCI hardware device, so this option is also not applicable to you. Honestly I also have no idea how this works in detail.

## 3. A file in an EFI System Partition.

As mentioned in the Driver Writer's Guide, one needs to save the driver bin on an EFI System Partition and then update the `Driver####` and `DriverOrder` UEFI variables.

To access the EFI System Partition in Windows, run `cmd` as admin and enter `mountvol X: /S`, replace `X` with whichever drive letter is unused on your computer. Note that access still requires admin privilege and you won't be able to see the mounted drive in Explorer. See edit history for a longer method using `diskpart`.

Now to update the `Driver####` and `DriverOrder` UEFI variables, you can write either a UEFI application, or a Win32 application. Section '3.1.1 Boot Manager Programming' of the [UEFI Specification Version 2.8](https://uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/UEFI_Spec_2_8_final.pdf)  provides some background on how these variables are processed and section '3.1.3 Load Options' details the data structure and constants involved. For UEFI application, use `SetVariable()` (section '8.2 Variable Services' of the spec). For Win32, use [`SetFirmwareEnvironmentVariableA`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setfirmwareenvironmentvariablea) or [`SetFirmwareEnvironmentVariableExA`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setfirmwareenvironmentvariableexa).

For a Win32 sample, you can take a look at the [dumpEfiVars](https://github.com/veracrypt/dumpEfiVars) project. It only reads the variables and doesn't write to them, but the code can be easily adapted to perform writing. You can also use the tool to dump the `Boot####` and `BootOrder` variables of a test computer to get a sense of what `Driver####` and `DriverOrder` should look like. Most computers would not have any 3rd party UEFI drivers installed on an EFI System Partition, so their `Driver####` and `DriverOrder` variables would be empty.

P.S. This question feels more appropriate in stackoverflow rather than superuser. Also your question on a flag for your driver deserves a separate post.

Comment: Just an FYI, the EFI partition is no longer writable on Windows 10... The only way I know of to _possibly_ write to the partition is during the Windows install process, within the WinPE or Specialize [pass](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-setup-configuration-passes).

Comment: @JW0914 are you able to double check this? I'm able to create a directory and copy a file into it on Win10 1903. Perhaps you're referring to the Recovery partition that houses the [Windows Recovery Environment](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-recovery-environment--windows-re--technical-reference)?

Comment: I'm able to mount mine, but it's not GUI accessible.  After some experimenting, I can `cd ` into it, and transfer files via cli, but it remains GUI inaccessible.  Trying to open it in Explorer warns I don't have permission to access it, and selecting Continue loads a permission denied error even though I gave myself permissions via `icacls`.  The Security Tab is also missing from properties and greyed out in the drive context menu.

Comment: @JW0914 I believe access to it requires admin privilege, and Explorer only runs with regular user privilege. Hence an elevated cmd can access it but not Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread but still, my experience in mounting an EFI partition is to use the Minitool Partition Wizard https://www.partitionwizard.com/, which will literally allow you to assign a letter to the partition but then launching explorer++ https://explorerplusplus.com/ as admin (right click the executable for context menu) will allow you to modify, ie; add or delete items on the partition and then remove the letter again with the Partition Wizard.

Someone will find this useful. Cheers

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1208754)