# Add DXE driver to an OVMF image

Tags: drivers, uefi, qemu

This is an attempt to follow the first bullet point in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1489848/1742482).

#### Goal

Create a development environment to test that my DXE drivers are being properly injected into an UEFI firmware image.

#### First attempt

I have followed the `vmware-vmx.exe` injection [guide](https://github.com/pbatard/efifs/wiki/Adding-a-driver-to-a-UEFI-firmware) suggested in the previous link. This trick doesn't seem to work anymore as detailed in [this issue](https://github.com/pbatard/efifs/issues/40).

#### Second attempt

Instead of extracting VMWare's `bios.rom`, I used UEFITool on `OVMF.fd` to the same end.

Unfortunately, when I try to boot that `bios` with `QEMU`, the system hangs with the message `Guest has not initialized the display yet`.

I have tried to use `-D log.txt`, but no logs are written.

I have also tried to hook `gdb` to `QEMU` with the `-S -s` flags, but looking at assembly didn't help me understand what is failing.

###### My suspicion

If I had to pick a reason, I'd say that `secure boot` is enabled. This is not allowing the modified firmware image to run.

#### Third Attempt

I tried to build `OMVF.fd` with `edk2`, but the build has errors. If I manage to get the vanilla version working I'd then add my driver natively. But I haven't been able to understand how to do that yet.

#### Further attempts

###### 1 - Find out how to get QEMU logs

###### 2 - Find out how to disable `secure boot`

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/a/1423636) says that `OVMF_CODE.fd` allows secure boot to be comprised, but I haven't been able to find a `OVMF_CODE` file. This might be a viable solution.

###### 3 - Build `OVMF` myself, adding my driver natively

###### 4 - Any other suggestion?

Any help with my previous attempts would also be kindly appreciatted.

---

#### Edit, following progress

#### Second attempt

Removing one of the default DXE driver doesn't make it hang, adding it back doesn't make QEMU hang either.

Adding my driver makes it hang.

For logs to be written with `-D`, I also have to provide a `-d item`, where item is one of `-d help`, such as `int` for interrupts.

I haven't decoded this information yet, as [it seems](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/649663/418254) it's not exactly trivial to do so, but at least I have been able to evaluate if QEMU has crashed or not.

All logs have these `INT=0x20` and the PC alternates between these two:

```
Servicing hardware INT=0x20
   397: v=20 e=0000 i=0 cpl=0 IP=0038:0000000006c6e115 pc=0000000006c6e115 SP=0030:0000000007e876d0 env->regs[R_EAX]=0000000000344f61
```

And

```
Servicing hardware INT=0x20
   394: v=20 e=0000 i=0 cpl=0 IP=0038:0000000006c6e127 pc=0000000006c6e127 SP=0030:0000000007e876f0 env->regs[R_EAX]=00000000002fc599
```

###### Regarding my suspicion:

The `OVMF*.dsc` files start with:

```
  #
  # Defines for default states.  These can be changed on the command line.
  # -D FLAG=VALUE
  #
  DEFINE SECURE_BOOT_ENABLE      = FALSE
```

Which seems to imply that secure boot is disabled.

Nonetheless, I am using `QEMU` with the `-bios OVMF.fd` option, which [according to this post](https://github.com/kata-containers/kata-containers/issues/1231#issuecomment-755445413) is not supposed to and relates to this secure boot thing.

I still have to look into that. But I find it unlikely that secure boot is the problem given that I can modify the `OVMF` image through UEFITool.

#### Third attempt

In order to build `OVMF` without problems I had to install and use the `GCC5` toolchain:

`TOOL_CHAIN_TAG        = GCC5`

Adding my driver natively makes QEMU hang with:

`Guest has not initialized the display yet`

With the logs signalling an exception:

`check_exception old: 0xffffffff new 0x6`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a branch of EDK2 that includes your changes and you provide the exact steps you use to build OVMF, then it'll be much easier to help solve the issue. Without code, we can only give guesses that could be frustrating non-answers for you.

I'm including quotes from your post to the devel@edk2.groups.io mailing list since that mailing list is for code review and community management.

On Wed, Nov 2, 2022 at 7:02 AM d.meneses via groups.io d.meneses=softi9.pt@groups.io wrote:

> As detailed on this post on Super User, I am trying to add a DXE driver to an OVMF image I'm building with edk2. Nobody was able to help me there so I turn here for your help.
>  
> I haven't found any proper documentation on exactly what I'm trying to achieve so I am probably missing something.

I just recently figured out how to do this for my own simple DXE driver, CocoDxe, https://github.com/deeglaze/edk2/commit/2397a74ee097787f9e1dbacde213988270603bc8

> So far what I have done is:
>
> create the simplest DXE driver I managed
>
> In folder MdeModulePkg/Application/Hello, I have:
> Hello.c :
> include
>  
> ...
>  
> while (1)
>         SystemTable->ConOut->OutputString(SystemTable->ConOut,
>                                           L"It works!\n");

You might prefer

`Print(L"It works!\n");`

> return EFI_SUCCESS;
>
> Hello.inf :
> [Defines]
>   INF_VERSION                    = 0x00010005
>   BASE_NAME                      = Hello
>   FILE_GUID                      = ...

Did you use a fresh GUID?

> MODULE_TYPE                    = DXE_DRIVER
>   VERSION_STRING                 = 1.0
>   ENTRY_POINT                    = UefiMain

Generally I think that drivers use a prefix of their driver name before their public symbol names, like I have CocoDxeEntryPoint. I only see UefiMain in UEFI application sources, not DXE drivers. I'm not sure if the linker is picking some other UefiMain definition and causing your witnessed triple fault.

> [Sources]
>   Hello.c
>
> [Packages]
>   MdePkg/MdePkg.dec
>   MdeModulePkg/MdeModulePkg.dec
>
> [LibraryClasses]
>   UefiDriverEntryPoint
>   UefiLib
>
> [Depex]
>     TRUE
>
> Set OvmfPkg/OvmfPkgX64.dsc as my target platform with GCC5 as the toolchain
> Add MdeModulePkg/Application/Hello/Hello.inf to the end of the component section (I have tried to add it after other certain drivers) in the .dsc file.
> Yes, [Components] seems to be right.
> Add MdeModulePkg/Application/Hello/Hello.inf to the end of the [FV.DXEFV] section in OvmfPkgX64.fdf (I have also tried to add it after other certain drivers)

Yes, I think this is correct.

> Run build

What command? I follow the instructions on https://github.com/tianocore/edk2/blob/master/OvmfPkg/PlatformCI/ReadMe.md

> Run QEMU with the resulting OVMF image: qemu-system-x86_64 -d int -D log.txt  -bios OVMF.fd -net none -drive file=fat:rw:bootdrv,format=raw
> QEMU hangs with message "Guest has not initialized display (yet)"

What output do you get when you don't include your DXE driver?

> log.txt has one log: check_exception old: 0xffffffff new 0x6

This log appears to indicate a triple fault, which means something very wrong happened.

> *.*,*.*,_
>
> ---
>
> Groups.io Links:
>
> You receive all messages sent to this group.
>
> View/Reply Online (#95863) | | Mute This Topic | New Topic
> Your Subscription | Contact Group Owner | Unsubscribe [dionnaglaze@google.com]
>
> *.*,*.*,_